# Update blobs on duplicate entry in PDO

Tags: pdo, duplicates, blob

I have a MySQL table in which I am storing a sequence of app icons (various resolutions) as blob fields - each table row identifies an app and six icon images.  My SQL statement goes something like this

```sql
INSERT INTO `appicons` (apid,apd16,apd57,apd72,apd114,apd128,apd144) 
  VALUES (:a,:b,:c,:d,:e,:f,:g);
```

This works fine.  But given that each `appid` is unique I need to allow for the need to update the app icons.  So I tried

```sql
INSERT INTO `appicons` (apid,apd16,apd57,apd72,apd114,apd128,apd144) 
  VALUES (:a,:b,:c,:d,:e,:f,:g) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE apd16 = :bb;
```

Needless to say by binding the appropriate parameters in each case.  However, the update does not add the expected blob data to the table.  Instead I get a 1 byte entry in that blob field.

How does one go about updating a blob entries as I need to do here?

Comment: Show us your PDO code instead.

Comment: "INSERT INTO `appicons` (apid,apd16,apd57,apd72,apd114,apd128,apd144) VALUES (:a,:b,:c,:d,:e,:f,:g) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE apd16 = :bb";
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bindParam(':a',$sid);
 $stmt->bindParam(':b',$imd['16'],PDO::PARAM_LOB);
 $stmt->bindParam(':bb',$imd['16'],PDO::PARAM_LOB);
 $stmt->bindParam(':c',$imd['57'],PDO::PARAM_LOB);
 $stmt->bindParam(':d',$imd['72'],PDO::PARAM_LOB);
 $stmt->bindParam(':e',$imd['114'],PDO::PARAM_LOB);
 $stmt->bindParam(':f',$imd['128'],PDO::PARAM_LOB);
 $stmt->bindParam(':g',$imd['144'],PDO::PARAM_LOB);

Comment: In the post, not here, how am I supposed to read that?

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is this - when binding parameters to a prepared statement they have to be bound IN ORDER - even when using named parameters rather than ?? placeholders.  I had been binding the parameter for the update bit in the wrong order.

Comment: No, it's not needed. When you use :? placeholders obviously they have to be in order, when they are named they don't. If order mattered there wouldn't be any point with named placeholders.

Comment: Perhaps you are right or perhaps it depends on the flavor of PHP PDO in use?  In any case, with that change the blob update on duplicate is working right for me.

Comment: If that itself really solves the problem it's a bug that you should file. Does the same thing happen if you use PDO::PARAM_STR instead of PDO::PARAM_LOB?

Comment: Strangely enough, not with PDO::PARAM_STR.  This only seems to be an issue with my local WAMP server (2.2) installation which runs PHP 5.3.8.  On my server, which runs 5.3.2 I can bung in the named bound parameters any way I like.